# How to initialize @ReadOnly entities in JPA / EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I am using JPA2 and EclipseLink. I would like to use an entity with @ReadOnly annotation. So under normal conditions these entities are not supposed to be changed und unique as Java objects over the complete persistence unit.

But how can I initialize them? They need to arrive in the database somehow. Can I bootstrap them under specific circumstances - e.g. when I know that there are no other transactions and caches in use?

Comment: what is wrong with a traditional SQL insert?

Comment: Well, it's a bit ugly ;-) I would prefer leveraging the power of JPA O2R mapping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that @ReadOnly JPA entities shouldn't be written, so you can't use the PersistenceManager (via the persist() method) to initialize them.  You can however create a utility class that runs when your application starts and contains a statically created set of these entities as well as a bootstrap method that uses native queries to insert them into your database.

Obviously how you cause this class to execute will depend upon your application, but I'd also recommend making the class smart enough to only add the entities that aren't already in the database.  This way your class will be useful as your application is maintained.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. So there is no way to temporarily disable the "@ReadOnly" behavior? I have a "configuration mode" where I could ensure specific conditions (no cahces, no performance requirements, etc.). I would love to use JPA to persist this configuration data.

Comment: There is no way that I know of to temporarily disable @ReadOnly.

Comment: After some more research I found the method "addReadOnlyClass(B.class)" in the API for unit of work. A made some experiments - it seems that you can control the read-only property on a transaction level. Would exactly serve my needs. But I have not found too much to read about it. Any experiences?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'am facing the same problem... my only idea is to implement this caching feature by myself.

Comment: I'm now using FlywayDB (https://flywaydb.org/) to perform database migrations via my Maven builds - I simply add the needed read-only values using those migrations.